# My MySQL query not passing in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO info (admin_email,admin_pass,admin_user,website_name)
VALUES ($admin_email,$admin_pass,$admin_user,$website_name)");
```

The above is the mysql query, it is unfortunately not passing in php. I created the database "project" and the table "info". I connected it to the database (I checked it too). I don't know why this is not working, can somebod please give some comments on this?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing single quotes for the string values

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO info (admin_email,admin_pass,admin_user,website_name) 
VALUES ('$admin_email','$admin_pass','$admin_user','$website_name')");
```

> NOTE : Your code is vulnerable to sql injection so use prepared
>   Statement instead.

Comment: Yeah! I missed it! Had gone mad, having missed the single quotes. lolz! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your request in variable, as `$admin_pass`, `$admin_user` etc..
so to make it as string you will have to use single quotes you can directly use:

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO info (admin_email,admin_pass,admin_user,website_name) 
VALUES 
(".$_REQUEST['admin_email'].",".$_REQUEST['admin_pass'].",".$_REQUEST['admin_user'].",".$_REQUEST['website_name'].")");
```

Answer (score 0):

use prepared statements!

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "cctutorial_mysqli");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
    }

    /* Create the prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CodeCall (FirstName, LastName) values (?, ?)")) {

    /* Bind our params */

    //s symbilize is string
    //if you increase the fields increase also the s's :)
    //i corresponding variable has type integer
    //d corresponding variable has type double
    //s corresponding variable has type string
    //b corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $firstName, $lastName);

    /* Set our params */
    $firstName = "Jordan";
    $lastName = "DeLozier";

    /* Execute the prepared Statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* Echo results */
    echo "Inserted {$lastName},{$firstName} into database\n";

    /* Set our params for second query */
    $firstName = "John";
    $lastName = "Ciacia";

    /* Execute second Query */
    $stmt->execute();

    echo "Inserted {$lastName},{$firstName} into database\n";

    /* Close the statement */
    $stmt->close();
    }
    else {
    /* Error */
    printf("Prepared Statement Error: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
    }

?>
```